# Jenkins-X: How to link external service in preview environment

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-x

From preview environment I want to access a database located in staging environment (in namespace `jx-staging`).

I am trying to follow [Service Linking](https://jenkins-x.io/developing/preview/#adding-more-resources) from Jenkins-X documentation with no success. Documentation is not really clear where to put the service link definition.

I created a service file `charts/preview/resources/mysql.yaml` with following content, but the service link is not created.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: mysql.jx-staging.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 3306
```

JX Environment:

```
jx version:
NAME               VERSION
jx                 1.3.688
jenkins x platform 0.0.3125
Kubernetes cluster v1.10.9-gke.5
kubectl            v1.10.7
helm client        v2.12.1+g02a47c7
helm server        v2.12.0+gd325d2a
git                git version 2.11.0
Operating System   Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
```

Where and how to define a service link?

GitHub issue: [How to link external service in preview environment](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/2604)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to move `mysql.yaml` from `resources` to `templates` sub-folder:

```
charts/preview/templates/mysql.yaml
```

Issue was cause by a typo in [Service Linking](https://jenkins-x.io/developing/preview/#adding-more-resources) documentation which is now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

BTW there is also a [FAQ entry on adding more resources to a preview](https://jenkins-x.io/faq/develop/#how-do-i-add-other-services-into-a-preview).

Your `Service` YAML looks good to me. Do you see the `Service` created when you create a Preview Environment?

You can find the namespace by typing `jx get preview` then to see if there is a `Service` in your environment try `kubectl get service -n jx-myuser-myapp-pr-1`

Comment: Hi James. The "link service" does not get created in preview env. namespace. Only a service for the application is created - in total I have one service in preview env. namespace.